# Return an array from a function with a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I need to return the array `lotSpecItems` from this function once it is populated:

```
public getLotSpecItems(id: number) {
    let toReturn = this.resourceClass.getLotSpecItems({ lotId: id });
    let lotSpecItems = [];
    return toReturn.$promise.then(lotSpecItemsArray => {
        lotSpecItemsArray.forEach(lotSpecItem => {
            lotSpecItems.push(this.$di.logicFactory.getLotSpecLogic().mapLotSpecItem(lotSpecItem));
        });
    });
}
```

The `$promise` is an angular js promise: `(property) angular.resource.IResourceArray<any>.$promise: ng.IPromise<ng.resource.IResourceArray<any>>`

Client code (can be edited to not expect a promise):

```
$onInit() {
    this.lotLogic.getLotSpecItems(this.lot.id).then((results) => {
        this.searchResults = results;
        console.log(this.searchResults);
    });
```

It currently returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why questions like this get down votes. This question provides the minimum code to identify the problem, describes the actual behavior and explains the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from the `$promise.then()`. Return your new array so it is available in the next `then()`

```
public getLotSpecItems(id: number) {
    let toReturn = this.resourceClass.getLotSpecItems({ lotId: id });
    let lotSpecItems = [];
    return toReturn.$promise.then(lotSpecItemsArray => {
        lotSpecItemsArray.forEach(lotSpecItem => {
            lotSpecItems.push(this.$di.logicFactory.getLotSpecLogic().mapLotSpecItem(lotSpecItem));
        });
        // Now return the array
        return lotSpecItems; 
    });
}
```